# A word for how much of a sales target has been acomplished

Tags: expressions, nouns

Imagine the user interface of a sales commission management system.

You have clearly labeled **Goal** showing the amount in sales the sales representative has to sell in order to reach it.

Then there is another field that displays how much the sales representative has sold already. Let's say this field is labelled **Status**. It could also be labelled **Sales Closed**.

Finally, there is a field showing the percentage of the **Goal** that the sales representative has achieved (basically, the value of the **Status** field divided by the value of the **Goal** field).

The question is, how should this field be labelled?

Options that have already been considered:

- **Progress**: looks weird when the user has already surpassed their goal (e.g. **Progress: 120%**).
- **Percentage**: feels like it's missing context (i.e. "percentage of what?").

Ideally, it should be a single word or a couple of words, like **Sales Closed**.

Comment: I would just say "Percentage of sales closed" or "% Sales Closed",  "Sales Closed (%)" or just "Sales Closed %".  When it comes to labelling things on a chart, space is at a premium and the rules of grammar aren't as important as whether your audience will intuitively understand what each label means.

Comment: Does the underlying platform allow conditional labels?  That is, could you use "Progress" up until goal, and a different label for at and above goal?  If so, try a synonym of "surplus" or "overage."

Comment: Percent of quota.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest

> Fulfillment - The achievement of something desired, promised, or predicted.

Or

> Attained - reach a specified age, size, or amount.

E.G

Goal: $5,656

Status: $6,453.9

Fulfillment/Attained: 142%

Comment: Thanks @grumpycrouton, indeed, it approximates well the meaning I want. Unfortunately, "Fulfillment" is a word that is used in the same context as part of another expression with a different meaning, ["Order Fulfillment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_fulfillment), so it would be nice if there was another word, so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: @LeoRochael Perhaps a close synonym then? Attained for example? `reach (a specified age, size, or amount).`

Comment: hmm, your "Attained" suggestion is not bad, if perhaps a little uncommon (in the sense that it's a word that is not used so frequently). Maybe something like "Accomplished: XX %" would work...

Comment: @LeoRochael Yeah accomplished would be another synonym.